# OpenVPN - tun or tap to access devices remotely with a public IPv6

Tags: vpn, openvpn, nas, ipv6

**My situation**

I am working with a MacBook and a Windows Laptop. At home I use a QNAP NAS as my central data storage in order to have the same data available on both laptops. I Also use the NAS as my time machine back-up.

**My Goal**

When I work remote I would like to have secure access from both laptops and my smartphone to the data on my NAS and I would like to use the NAS back-up volume to backup my MacBook using time machine. Therefore I want to setup OpenVPN on an additional machine in my home net which is accessible with an IPv6 address, since I have a DS-Lite internet connection.

**Question**

Should I configure the OpenVPN as tun or tap to get access to my NAS from the three devices as intended?

While I was studying this topic I found the information that it is not possible to use smb "based" applications with tun. However, I connect my MacBook with the NAS via smb to get access to my files. (Not sure which protocol time machine uses). If I understand it correct, tap would be suitable? However, from the documentation I have been reading so far, it is not possible to connect smartphones with the OpenVPN when using tap.
What would be the recommended approach in my case?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should investigate some more about Time Machine. Back in the days it could only work over AFP, but apparently it now also works with SMB. Maybe use Wireshark to see what’s happening. // You could always have multiple OpenVPN daemons with different configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Both work equally well for a basic VPN that just carries IP-based protocols. So if you need to connect client devices which only support 'tun' mode, then the simplest option is to just use 'tun' mode.

- 'tun' (and 'ppp') devices carry "bare" IPv4/IPv6 packets, with no lower-layer header – for example, there are no MAC addresses and devices do not make ARP queries.
- 'tap' devices carry full Ethernet frames, which might contain IPv4/IPv6 inside or some other protocol entirely. In other words a 'tap'-based VPN works almost exactly the same as an Ethernet cable.

So you would only need 'tap' mode if you wanted to transport other protocols than IP (e.g. EtherTalk for 1980s Macs), or if you wanted to bridge both ends of the VPN into one large Ethernet subnet (e.g. if you had to use some IoT apps that relied on broadcast packets).

Comment: Thank you both. I have done more research in the meantime. Even if most documents say one should prefer tun, if possible, tap seems to fit my needs better (except the fact that I cannot access the VPN with my smartphone). Is a tap-VPN more risky since I can transport more than IP protocols or is the OpenVPN software robust enough to neglect the security aspect? Of course I don't want a guarantee. Just a personal valuation. Thank you :)

Comment: Well, in tap mode the VPN software doesn't even care what other protocols you transport over it. It works like an Ethernet switch most of the time, forwarding packets purely by each client's (virtual) MAC address. But maybe it's not supported by Android OS because it might expose the *endpoint device* to more risk?...